# Actual Debug Symbols for ASP.NET MVC 2 Release Version

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I need the actual debug symbols from the released version of ASP.NET MVC 2 (the version that gets installed via the web platform installer).

I know I can download the source, build and use the debug symbols from that. But there are a couple issues with that approach:

- Requires that all other dependencies be rebuilt using this version of the DLL since it's not signed. This isn't feasible if you are using 3rd party libraries which don't provide the source.
- The built version from the latest source doesn't match the release version (possibly because of the difference in signing alone). So I can't reference that .pdb.
- I don't want a dependency on a custom build or any build other than the one that get's installed from a standard install.

I just need the debugging symbols so I can step through the source without introducing a different dll. I tried to use the public Microsoft Symbol Server, but it's not downloading the symbols for this dll.

Anyone know if this .pdb exists?

(I know that it's possible to generate and step through this dll using the newer version of Reflector - but that's for the professional version and costs money now.)

Comment: I really wish I could up this question more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the MS Symbol Server (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SetUpYourSystemToUseMicrosoftsPublicSymbolServer.aspx) to find those.

Comment: Seems they have now added those symbols to the MS Public Symbol server. So this works now. Just be sure to also download the source and point the debugger to that source when prompted (when you are stepping through the call stack for example).