# Is there a way to debug ASP.NET MVC code using a symbol server (instead of downloading the source and referencing that)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, symbol-server

Is it possible to step through the official ASP.NET MVC 2 code via using the Symbol Server thingy in visual studio 2010?

I know I can download the full open source MVC code from codeplex, build it and then get my code to reference THAT codebase dll's...

But i'm wondering if this could be achieved by using the Symbol Server stuff instead?

If so, can someone go through some steps please, about how to achieve this?

Comment: Check [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525835/actual-debug-symbols-for-asp-net-mvc-2-release-version) for an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symbols have recently been added to the Microsoft Public Symbol server.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SetUpYourSystemToUseMicrosoftsPublicSymbolServer.aspx

=====

Freshly blogged for you :-)

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/04/21/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-to-step-into-microsoft-net-source-code.aspx

Comment: that's a post way back from 2006. is that still accurate/valid (against vs2010) ?

Comment: What about now? Are there symbols for MVC 4?